# How do I set a global variable via function call?

Tags: python

I am trying to change the value of global variable `edl_loading` to `True` in function `edl_flashing` ,somehow it doesn't work?can anyone help understand why does `print edl_loading` prints `False` after call to `edl_flashing` in which I change the value to `True`

```
def edl_flashing():
    edl_loading = True
    print edl_loading


def main ():
    global edl_loading
    edl_loading = False
    print edl_loading
    edl_flashing()
    print edl_loading #Why this prints as False
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

OUTPUT:-

```
False
True
False
```

Comment: `edl_loading` in `edl_flashing` is local to that function.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `global` in both of your functions - `main` and `edl_flashing`

```
def edl_flashing():
    global edl_loading
    edl_loading = True
    print edl_loading
```

Without the global declaration in the function, the variable name is local to the function.

The above change prints out

```
False
True
True
```

Comment: If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted. Not only for the question, but for any other questions that you would ask in future.